# gedit and gksu a file

Tags: 14.04, gedit, gksu

I tried to edit a php file using `gedit` and `sudo gksu` 

I got following error message using `gedit mytext.php`.

```
 gedit mytext.php

(gedit:2644): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkScrolledWindow 0x17d4880 is mapped but visible child GtkScrollbar 0x17dacb0 is not mapped
```

Ubuntu prompt me to enter password but it does not run edit program using `sudo gksu mytext.php`

```
sudo gksu mytext.php
```

I have the file on the `/home/myuser/Documents/myproject` where I should have full access.
Here are the typing and error message,

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Your help and information is great appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar
```

Taken from here: http://pastebin.com/2bENRMf2

Comment: thanks for the information and help, there is no error message when I use gedit mytext.php, but sudo gksu mytext.php still does not run any application to edit the file, thanks again, Iccsi,

Comment: If you need to _sudo_ that file in order to open it in Gedit, try this:

`gksudo gedit mytext.php`

Note that you don't need that extra `sudo`, because _gksu*_ is a _su*_ front-end itself.

Comment: Always a pleasure :)